# Firefox session/cookie handling on forms

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, cookies

I have page which has a poll form, the user vote in the form and when submitted will call an ajax request to show the result on the form.

Upon voting a cookie will be created marking that the user already voted in the poll. So that next time the user access the page the voting will be disabled for that user if the cookie is found.

My problem is when using firefox after voting and the user hit the url (go to url and press enter) again the user can still vote. Not until the user hit refresh button / press F5 that the user will be detected as voted.

This seems to happen only on firefox and not on Chrome and IE.

I will gladly provide more info if needed.

My method for creating and getting the cookie are in my java class.

```
public static void addCookie (RequestContext context, String key, String value){
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(key, value);
        cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
        context.getResponse().addCookie(cookie);

}

public static String getCookieValue(RequestContext context,
        String cookieName, String defaultValue) {
    String value;
    CookieHash cookies = context.getCookies();
    Cookie cookieValue = cookies.getCookie(cookieName);
    if (cookieValue == null) {
        value = defaultValue;
    } else {
        value = cookieValue.getValue();
    }
    return value;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting, as far as i know - you can access cookie in firefox as soon as you created it, no refresh needed.. how do you create and read cookie?
seeing your code where you create and read cookie would help greatly ;)

i personally am using these functions to create and read cookies:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days)
{
if (days)
{
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else
    var expires = "";

document.cookie = escape(name)+"="+escape(value)+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name)
{
var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

for ( var i=0; i < ca.length; i++ )
{
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length));
}
return false;
}
```

so following code will work perfectly for me:

```
createCookie('myCookieName', 1, 30);
var cookieValue = readCookie('myCookieName');
if(cookieValue == 1)
{
   /* some action here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ajax , the hxrhttprequest object is implemented differently for Mozilla . I'm not sure though. Just a guess.